# "Безопасные" Java-based CMS

Tags: java, cms

Может ли кто-нибудь посоветовать Java-based CMS, которые более-менее стабильны в работе? Использовал до этого Magnolia, но был огорчен, когда при внезапном падении сервера она не смогла не только контент восстановить, но и сама не запускается.

Comment: Стойкость данных это Durability из ACID, и этим должна заниматься база данных. CMS немножко ни при чём.

Comment: В Magnolia у меня данные не в базе лежали, а в бинарниках (это в CMS предусмотрено). И по идее эти файлы остались, но вот прочитать их не может она

Comment: Значит, есть смысл взять любую CMS, использующую ACID-следующую БД :)